# Unmount not working

Tags: command-line, bash, mount, unmount

I have a mounted partition that can't be unmounted :

```
> sudo umount /dev/sdc1
umount: /home/me/mounts/sdc1: not mounted.
> sudo mount | grep sdc1
/dev/sdc1 on /home/me/mounts/sdc1 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

Any help ?

Edit:
I also tried :

```
> sudo umount /home/me/mounts/sdc1
Could not unlink the key(s) from your keying. Please use `keyctl unlink` if you wish to remove the key(s). Proceeding with umount.
umount: /home/me/mounts/sdc1: not mounted.
```

Comment: You've not provided any OS/product/release details; but you have tried unmounting the directory where it's mounted  (*what is usually unmounted*).

Comment: If the disk partition isn't `mount`ed, the `/home/me/mounts/sdc1` is simply a directory in the `/home/me/mounts` directory,  and knows nothing about `/dev/sdc1`. There's nothing to `umount` without a preceding `mount`.

Comment: @guiverc My system is ubuntu 20.04. I don't understand the second part of your comment; please explain a bit more.

Comment: @waltinator I don't understand your comment either. The 3rd and 4th lines of my code snippet show that it appears as being mounted.

Comment: Read `man mount fstab`. Your `sudo mount` actually `mount`ed the partition,  because of the `auto` option in `/dev/sdc1`'s entry in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: If what you're saying is that line3 mounted it, I don't think it's the case : if I start with line3 and then execute line1, the problem remains.

Comment: my *second part* was suggesting you try `sudo umount /home/me/mounts/sdc1`

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification, I tried it and the result is indeed different, though it's still not working. I edited my original post to append the result of that command

Comment: that's weird, can you do `sudo mount /dev/sdc1` and see if it gives you a mount error?

Comment: A .safer way is `df | grep sdc1;grep sdc1 /etc/fstab`|